# How do set NTLM authentication in Firefox using Webdriver for HTTPS application?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ntlm, remotewebdriver

I’m not able to login to a HTTPS application which has NTLM authentication using selenium Webdriver. But i’m able to login to the HTTP application which has NTLM auth.

i tried giving the username and password in URL.

```
driver.get("https://domain\\username:password@url");
```

and also tried,

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
Credentials cr=new UserAndPassword("domain\\username", "password");
alert.authenticateUsing(cr);
```